# Restore dialog after screen rotation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, material-design

i have dialog (material dialog from this  [lib](https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs) ) with 2 edittexts. After i rotated device activity is destroyed and the dialog as well. I know that edittext has autosave for input text, but how can i forbid dialog from being destroyed?

```
 MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context).customView(R.layout.dialog_edit_point_info, false)
            .positiveText(R.string.ok).negativeText(R.string.cancel)
            .positiveColorRes(R.color.dark_blue).negativeColorRes(R.color.black)
            .iconRes(R.drawable.ic_marker_location)
            .autoDismiss(false)
            .title(R.string.edit_title_dialog).callback(callback).build;
```

Comment: Use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your dialog inside an DialogFragment:

```
public static class MyAlertDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    MaterialDialog dialog = new MaterialDialog.Builder(context).customView(R.layout.dialog_edit_point_info, false)
        .positiveText(R.string.ok).negativeText(R.string.cancel)
        .positiveColorRes(R.color.dark_blue).negativeColorRes(R.color.black)
        .iconRes(R.drawable.ic_marker_location)
        .autoDismiss(false)
        .title(R.string.edit_title_dialog).callback(callback).build();

}
}
```

To call your dialog:

```
void showDialog() {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new MyAlertDialogFragment();
    newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "dialog");
}
```

You will find more information here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html

If you use Support-Libs use the corresponding support classes: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/DialogFragment.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this [lib](https://github.com/eltos/SimpleDialogFragments/wiki/SimpleDialog) insteat of your. It is widely customizable, shows dialogs as a `DialogFragment` and can show dialog called from other dialog.